# inserting multiple text files

Tags: variables, ssis, connection-string, foreach-loop-container

I have 4 different text files each file with different name and different column in it place in one folder. I want these 4 four files to be inserted or updated into 4 different existing tables. So How to read read these 4 files dynamically and insert them into their respective table dynamically in SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to use **Data Flow Task** to move data from a **Flat File Source** to a Table Destination (**OLEDB Destination** perhaps). Are the columns in your file delimited in any way? For example, with any of these: **(;),(|)** or something like that? if it is, you can create a **FlatFileConnectionManager** and set that to split the columns. If not, you might need to use the FixedWidth option to separate your columns. To use the OLEDB Destination, you will need to create a **OLEDB connectionManager** to point to the table in your database. I could help you more if I had more information about the files you want to read the data from.

**EDIT**

Well you said at the start you were working with 4 files and 4 tables, so you can create 4 Flat Destination sourcers with 4 OLEDB destinations aswell (1 of each for each flat file). If I understood you correctly, these 4 files can or cannot exist yet. So if you know the names that the files will get, change the Package Property **DelayValidation** to true, and then create a connection with a sample text file. You do this so the File path gets saved. The tables, in my opinion DO need to exist. Now, when you said:

> i want to load all the text files into each different existing table whenever there is files inside the folder.

The only way I know you can do something similar, is to schedule the execution of your package at a certain time with **SQL Server Agent Job**. Please let me know if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: yes the text files are delimited. I want to create a single package to load all these delimited text files at once to different tables and then archive the files to diff location

Comment: @Jason312 ok then. Like I said you need to use Data Flow Task, and inside just drag FlatFileSource and stablish a connectionMannager to it, do the same with the OLEDB Destination. I would suggest to create a table with the same columns as one of the 4 you want to insert to. [You will find this tutorial very useful](https://katieandemil.academy/create-ssis-package-find-an-example-how-to-create-an-ssis-package-a-simple-one)

Comment: I am new to ssis but your way is just simple flat file input. My purpose of this project automate the process. i want to load all the text files into each different existing table whenever there is files inside the folder. For example A text file to A table, B text file to B table and etc. I tried to use foreachloop but it only goes to the same destination. How to make the destination dynamic and also because some of the records are duplicated, how to use lookup function to connect with these tasks?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, I'm going to edit my answer